# Slider not updating in other functions

Tags: ios, swift, slider

I have a slider in my Xcode project that ranges from the numbers 0.1 - 1.0. I have it set up to display the current value in a label (which works). The problem I am having is when I try to call for the current value in another function it doesn't update in that function.

```
var currentValue = Float(1.0)

class Hello : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

@IBAction func SliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    SliderVar()
}

func SliderVar() {
    var currentValue = Float(Slider.value)
    Label.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

The label correctly displays the value. However if I call the `SlideVar()` function in another function it doesn't show the correct value.

For example:

```
func test() {

SlideVar()
println(currentValue)

}
```

The output shows the original value of 1.0 even though the slider and label are not on that value. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This must have been answered before. With `var currentValue = ...` in `SliderVar ` you declare a *new* variable local to that method. Just remove the `var`.

Comment: True thanks I am not very smart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `var` in front of `currentValue` in `SliderVar`.  You are creating a new local variable that is hiding your class property so the class property value is not getting updated:

```
func SliderVar() {
    currentValue = Float(Slider.value)
    Label.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```